# Something like 'contains any' for Java set?

Tags: java

I have two sets, A and B, of the same type.

I have to find if A contains any element from the set B.

What would be the best way to do that without iterating over the sets?
The Set library has `contains(object)` and `containsAll(collection)`, but not `containsAny(collection)`.

Comment: Are you trying to avoid iterating for efficiency reasons, or for code cleanliness?

Answer (score 262, accepted):

## `Stream::anyMatch`

Since Java 8 you could use [`Stream::anyMatch`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#anyMatch(java.util.function.Predicate)).

```
setA.stream().anyMatch(setB::contains)
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Thanks :-)
I also didn't know you could use variables with the :: syntax!

Comment: @blevert, could you explain what happen inside anyMatch ?

Comment: @Cristiano here, `anyMatch` will stream all of the elements from `setA` and call `setB.contains()` on all of them.  If "true" is returned for any of the elements, the expression as a whole will evaluate to true.  Hope this helped.

Comment: @Cristiano https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#anyMatch-java.util.function.Predicate-

Comment: This works, but it's inefficient if `setA` is large. The right answer is to call `Collections.disjoint`.

Comment: The efficiency of anyMatch is the same as efficiency of Collections.disjoint.

Comment: @gpl What are you basing this on?

Comment: I based it on `Collections.disjoint` source code. If both passed `Collection`s are `java.util.Set`s, then there is no check which one is used to iterate over. You might end up with iterating over large set, which gives you the same performance as `anyMatch` in case `setA` is large.

`Collections.disjoint` is in fact more versatile. It performs well with any `Collection` type, which is not true for `anyMatch` solution. The OP question was about Java sets, but performance for different collection types is with mentioning.

Answer (score 657):

Wouldn't [`Collections.disjoint(A, B)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#disjoint%28java.util.Collection,%20java.util.Collection%29) work? From the documentation:

> Returns `true` if the two specified collections have no elements in common.

Thus, the method returns `false` if the collections contains any common elements.

Comment: Prefer this to the other solutions because it does not modify either of the sets or creates a new one.

Comment: And is standard JRE, and works with any Collections, not just set.

Comment: I don't think this is speediest, it won't short-circuit when the first element of the intersection is found.

Comment: Actually it will short-circuit as soon as it finds the first common element

Comment: @Xipo is right. Check http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/Collections.java#Collections.disjoint%28java.util.Collection%2Cjava.util.Collection%29

Comment: @LluisMartinez Link appears to be dead.

Comment: It returns a 503 Service Unavailable, not 404. Maybe the server is down and the person responsible on vacation :-)

Comment: Be careful with equating "not disjoint" and "contains any".

`setA.containsAll(setB)` returns `true` when `setB` is empty. So it reasons that `setA.containsAny(setB)` would also return `true`. However, `!Collections.disjoint(setA, setB)` returns `false`, as all sets are disjoint from the empty set.

Comment: @Wesley - no, `setA.containsAny(emptySet())` is false. There's no reason `containsAll` being true would imply that `containsAny` must also be true.

Answer (score 56):

Apache Commons has a method [`CollectionUtils.containsAny()`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/CollectionUtils.html#containsAny-java.util.Collection-java.util.Collection-).

Comment: The syntax of using this is beautiful. You can also do `CollectionUtils.containsAny(mySet, "value1", "value2")`

Comment: @ManishSingh I see only two arguments, even in spring framework's CollectionUtils

Comment: I can see multiple arguments too - https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/src-html/org/apache/commons/collections4/CollectionUtils.html#line.422

Answer (score 41):

A good way to implement containsAny for sets is using the Guava [Sets.intersection()](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Sets.html#intersection-java.util.Set-java.util.Set-).

`containsAny` would return a `boolean`, so the call looks like:

```
Sets.intersection(set1, set2).isEmpty()
```

This returns true iff the sets are disjoint, otherwise false. The time complexity of this is likely slightly better than retainAll because you dont have to do any cloning to avoid modifying your original set.

Comment: The only disadvantage of using this approach is you have to include guava libraries. Which I think is not disadvantage because google collection APIs are very strong.

Comment: @DidierL most of the Guava Collections utility functions, including this one, return _views_ of the data structures. So there is no "building the set" to worry about in this case. The implementation is interesting to read here, and/or see the javadoc: https://google.github.io/guava/releases/21.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Sets.html#intersection-java.util.Set-java.util.Set-

Comment: @MohammadAdnan Another disadvantage is that it computes the full intersection - if set1 and set2 are very large, this would be plenty more resource intensive (both CPU and memory wise) than just checking if they have any item in common.

Comment: @MohammadAdnan That is not the only disadvantage. In `containsAny` logic you should, if not must, return as soon as a match is found but this method will run until `end-of-data` reached in both sets

Answer (score 28):

I use  *org.apache.commons.collections.CollectionUtils*

```
CollectionUtils.containsAny(someCollection1, someCollection2)
```

**That is All!**
Returns **true** if at least one element is in both collections.

Simple to use, and the name of the function is more suggestive.

Answer (score 5):

Use `retainAll()` in the Set interface. This method provides an intersection of elements common in both sets. See the API docs for more information.

Comment: If the point of avoiding the iteration is for efficiency, `retainAll` probably won't help. Its implementation in `AbstractCollection` iterates.

Comment: yshavit is correct. Given that the O.P. is looking to see if **any** element exists in both sets, a proper algorithm would have an `O(1)` running time in the best case, whereas `retainAll` would have something along the lines of an `O(N)` (it would depend on the size of only 1 set) best-case running time.

Comment: retainAll is destructive. It removes non common elements from the original List or Set. It gets an issue if you are in a loop and need to preserve the initial collection.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend creating a `HashMap` from set A, and then iterating through set B and checking if any element of B is in A. This would run in `O(|A|+|B|)` time (as there would be no collisions), whereas `retainAll(Collection<?> c)` must run in `O(|A|*|B|)` time.

Answer (score 3):

There's a bit rough method to do that. 
If and only if the A set contains some B's element than the call

```
A.removeAll(B)
```

will modify the A set. In this situation removeAll will return true (As stated at [removeAll docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/AbstractSet.html#removeAll%28java.util.Collection%29)). But probably you don't want to modify the A set so you may think to act on a copy, like this way:

```
new HashSet(A).removeAll(B)
```

and the returning value will be true if the sets are not distinct, that is they have non-empty intersection.

Also see [Apache Commons Collections](http://commons.apache.org/collections/api-2.1.1/org/apache/commons/collections/CollectionUtils.html#containsAny%28java.util.Collection,%20java.util.Collection%29)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [retainAll](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#retainAll%28java.util.Collection%29) method and get the intersection of your two sets.

Comment: In most cases one needs to keep the original set, so in order to use `retainAll` it's necessary to make a copy of the original set. Then it's more efficient to use `HashSet` as suggested by [Zéychin](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8708783/1333025) .

Comment: That's a state change, not condition check