# Iterating through a collection of objects to find an object efficiently

Tags: java, performance, loops, web-applications, collections

I have a list of fruit objects and I need to check if it contains a particular fruit. What is the most efficient way to do this? 
The list of fruits may contain hundreds of thousands of fruits and this method will be called in a loop.

Should I iterate through all the fruits in the list each time `isMyFruitInFruits(..)` is called? Or is there a better approach.

I also tried creating `List<Map<int, Fruit>>`, but this also requires iterating through the list sequentially everytime  `isMyFruitInFruits(..)` is called.

```
public void myMethod(){
    for(Fruit fruit : fruits){
        isMyFruitInFruits(fruit);
    }
}

List<Fruit> fruits
private boolean isMyFruitInFruits(Fruit fruit){
        fruits = dao.getFruits();
        .... how to check?
}
```

Comment: Ignoring the code smell of "isMyFruitInFruits" (with a name like that, I can't imagine a time where you would have a `fruit` yet it's not in the same-named group of `fruits`. If you have something you know is a fruit, why would it not be in the fruit group? Unless you're passing in the fruit group you want to compare).... Yes just do it in a list. Not sure what you're looking for. What other way than iterating your list and checking, when you have a list and you want to check something for each member of the list?

Comment: Would converting this list to a set or any other collection before doing the search be more efficient ?

Comment: Using a Set would remove any duplicates from the original list (provided that you override/implement `equals` for the object in a good way). Doing this of course adds overhead since the Set will compare the entry to every current entry every time you add a record to it (thus looping over the unique list every time something is added). Only use a `Set` if you care about uniqueness being enforced (it will be less efficient/performant i.e. slower).

Comment: I'd suggest you stick with the list to keep things simple (and relatively flexible for when you know you need to change it). Then test performance. But yes generally it can be a problem if you have too large of a list. But I've worked in applications where we had in-memory lists that were quite large, and that's not necessarily a bad thing (until the host machine can't handle it, then it is a bad thing)

Comment: We need more details about what you're actually checking, what data you're working with, where the data is coming from. It's unclear to me what you're trying to do in the code. You have a list and you're checking if each member of the list is already in the DB?

Comment: Yes that is what I am checking... ie if each member of the list is already in the DB.

Comment: What will be expensive/and take time is each different time you call the DB. If you're concerned you will have a large list and need to query the DB many times, you may want to do some paging. Either way there's no silver bullet and with performance issues, you just need to test it out (to see what is actually a problem, where it's a problem), and then you know where to make some assumptions about how to make it faster. But as to your question! Yes. A list. If that's what you're model'ing in your app (not a dictionary or set etc)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115756/discussion-between-mmcrae-and-nero).

Comment: One other key thing I noticed (not sure why I missed it at first), but you need to NOT call the DB to get the list every time. call dao.getFruits() first. Then, loop over your fruits list and compare it to the list you got from dao.getFruits(). Definitely do not call dao.getFruits() for every single item in your fruits list. Call it ahead of time, and then do a nested loop

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Something like 'contains any' for Java set?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8708542/something-like-contains-any-for-java-set)