# How to use assertNotEquals for 2 lists of different size

Tags: java, junit4, assert, assertions

I'm trying to assert two List of Strings having different number of elements.
I'm testing an application and my goal is to Fail a test case if the Actual list contains even one element that matches the Expected list.

I have tried below approaches but none of these suffice my requirement.

```
List<String> expected = Arrays.asList("fee", "fi", "foe", "foo");
List<String> actual = Arrays.asList("feed", "fi"); 
assertThat(actual, not(equalTo(expected)));`
```

I want this comparision yo fail since there is 1 element in actual list which matches the expected one.

```
Assert.assertNotEquals(actual,expected);
assertThat(actual, is(not(expected)));
Assert.assertNotEquals(actual, containsInAnyOrder(expected));
```

None of these work. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you explain "if the Actual list contains even one element that matches the Expected list."?

Comment: If you want to check to see if they have a different number of elements, then you want to compare actual.size() to expected.size() right?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Something like 'contains any' for Java set?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8708542/something-like-contains-any-for-java-set)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a one-liner.

```
Assert.assertTrue(Collections.disjoint(list1, list2));
```

The `disjoint` method returns `true` if its two arguments have no elements in common.

It helps to know the libraries that come with the JDK.  See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#disjoint-java.util.Collection-java.util.Collection-

Answer (score 0):

```
List<String> commonElement = findCommon(actual,expected);    
public List<String> findCommon(List<String> list1, List<String> list2) {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

        for (String t : list1) {
            if(list2.contains(t)) {
                list.add(t);
            }
        }

        return list;
    }

Assert.assertTrue(commonElement.size() != 0); //This will fail when actual`
```

list contains any element in expected list or vice-versa.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this:

```
    List<String> expected = Arrays.asList("fee", "fi", "foe", "foo");
    List<String> actual = Arrays.asList("feed", "fi");

    assert(actual.size() != expected.size()); // Will fail if same number of elements
    for(String s : actual){
        assert(!expected.contains(s)); // Fails if element in actual is in expected
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using `assertFalse` if any of the elements of actual list matches with any element in expected list as below:

```
    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception{
        List<String> expected = Arrays.asList("fee", "fi", "foe", "foo");
        List<String> actual = Arrays.asList("feed", "fi1"); 
        for(String temp : expected) {
            if(!actual.stream().noneMatch((String s) -> s.equals(temp))) {
                Assert.assertFalse(true);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I believe that OP wants to check if **any** element in `actual` appears in `expected`. This compares the two arrays are exact matches.