# A list contains at least one value from another list (Java 8)

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

My function finds if from a list of given words at list one word is valid in the page.
So when page contains words I have written it as follows:
(Simplified version)

```
private boolean atLeastOneWordIsValidInThePage(Page page, Set<Long>  wordIdsToCheck) 
    Set<Long> wordIds = page.getWords().stream()
                .filter(word -> word.isValid())
                .map(word->getWordId())
                .collect(Collectors.toSet());
return words.stream().anyMatch((o) -> wordIds.contains(o));
```

Is it the best java 8 practice to write it?
I want to stop searching when the first match is found.

Comment: I guess collecting stream into a set must have the same complexity as doing a set based lookup. So no need to construct `wordIds` in my opinion.

Comment: Some interesting approaches are in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8708542/something-like-contains-any-for-java-set (just scroll through all the answers).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no need to open two separate streams. You should be able to chain `anyMatch` directly to the `map` function as follows :

```
return page.getWords().stream()
            .filter(word -> word.isValid())
            .map(word->getWordId())
            .anyMatch((o) -> words.contains(o));
```

Comment: You can even drop the `(o) ->` and use method reference.

Comment: @PavelHoral Fair point. Trying to keep the code as close to the OPs code.

Comment: Also there is probably a typo in the OPs code regarding the `map` (missing `word.`)... but that is issue with the question, not the answer.

Comment: @PavelHoral I didn't follow that. `word` is the lambda parameter right?

Comment: It should be probably `word -> word.getWordId()`... but that must be confirmed by the OP.

Comment: @PavelHoral I see. I wouldn't want to change or address something that is not being asked directly or indirectly as it has a chance of backfiring in most cases.