# Quick way to determine whether a list contains at least one item contained in an array

Tags: java, arrays, list

I have a `List<String> a` and a `String[] b`. I would like to return true if there is at least one member of the list inside the array. For that matter, it doesn't matter that I am dealing with a `List<String>` and an `String[]`. Both could be lists.

### EDIT

Java 8 gives you a way to [do it via streams](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41920852/a-list-contains-at-least-one-value-from-another-list-java-8), it seems. What about more basic ways?

Thanks

Comment: the most basic way might be loop ?

Comment: I am not sure why you ask a question and then VTC as a duplicate of another question...

Comment: @Frakcool, yeah I thought it was the same but it is not...

Comment: @Ravi is that the only way? Seems too simple but then again...

Comment: @DavidBrossard as you mentioned *What about more basic ways*. Then, YES.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way without Java 8 streams:

```
public boolean containsAtLeastOne( List<String> a, String[] b ) {
    Set<String> aSet = new HashSet( a );
    for ( s : b ) {
       if ( aSet.contains( s ) ) {
           return true;
       }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Another way:

```
 public boolean containsAtLeastOne( List<String> a, String[] b ) {
    Set<String> aSet = new HashSet( a );
    List<String> bList = Arrays.asList(b);

    bList.retainAll( aSet );

    return 0 < bList.size();
 }
```