# How to check a list result as a HashMap value for a given String

Tags: java, hashmap

I have a HashMap. I want to check whether my individual arraylist (nodeList) values are contained within the values of my HashMap. In order to access the node values for a given way element in my Map, I used the getNodes method which has an output like this:

getNodes() returns a list<>Output: [Element N847744431 ({}), Element N847744763 ({})]

```
public class RoadNetwork{

   public void checkContent(){
    for(int i =0; i < nodeList.size(); i++){
            /* Does node(i) belong in the valueList of Way? */
         Set<Map.Entry<String, Element>> entrySet = wayList.entrySet();
            for (Map.Entry entry : entrySet){
               Way w1 = (Way) wayList.get(entry.getKey());
               //Check if Way contains node(i)
                if(w1.getNodes().contains(nodeList.get(i))){
                    System.out.println("Found something");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

public class Way{

  public List<Node> getNodes(){
      return nodes; 
  }
}
```

What can I do to work around this, I would like to check for a given value inside my hashmap, however the .contains() method isn't working in this case.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] (and format it as well as possible) rather than just snippets. Note that searching for a *value* in a `HashMap` defeats a lot of the point of a `HashMap`... it's optimized for *key* lookups.

Comment: There is no question..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Something like 'contains any' for Java set?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8708542/something-like-contains-any-for-java-set)

Answer (score 2):

(Edit : Oops ! I didn't see that the question was old. I'll keep the answer for the record)

Another solution would be using flatmap function to construct a list of nodes contained on the map, and then apply the anyMatch with a predicate to test the nodeList.get(i) existence on the map.

```
Boolean exists = wayList.values().stream().flatMap(Collection::stream).anyMatch(element -> element.equals(nodeList.get(i));
```

Of course, you should define both functions equals and hashcode for your Node type.

Answer (score 0):

Your example is unclear. For the question "How to check whether a value out of multiple values is within a HashMap", here's the answer:

```
// to check if at least one element of 'list' is present in 'map'
if(list.stream().filter(l -> map.containsKey(l)).collect(Collectors.toSet()).size() > 0) {
    // do stuff
}
```

Explanation:

- I'm using the Streams API of Java8.
- list.stream() would create a stream out of elements of the list, so that some lambda function can be applied on each of the elements (functional programming construct).
- The filter(l -> map.containsKey(l)) function will then check for which of the elements of list are present in the map. The output of the filter function will be another stream of elements that are present in both the list and the map.
- Collectors.toSet() function will convert this stream to a Set. It can be a List or some other collection as well, your choice.
- size() function just checks whether the resulting set is empty or not. If it is empty, no elements are common in both the list and the map, otherwise at least one element of the list is present in the map.

Comment: I appreciate the question isn't very clear to due to the nature of it being taken out of my program. However could you please explain how your if statement works?

Comment: The statement is self explanatory, still added the explanation.