# Which is the fastest way for a containsAny check?

Tags: java

in [Something like 'contains any' for Java set?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8708542/something-like-contains-any-for-java-set) there a several solutions

- Collections.disjoint(A, B)
- setA.stream().anyMatch(setB::contains)
- Sets.intersection(set1, set2).isEmpty()
- CollectionUtils.containsAny()

im my case set1 is `new ConcurrentHashMap<>().keySet()` and set2 is an `ArrayList`

set1 can cointain up to 100 entries, set2 less then 10

Or will they all do the same and perform similar?

Comment: You can do a benchmark test and you will know which one performs better in your scenario. In my opinion `Collections.disjoint(A, B)` should be preferred because it is provided built-in to Java's Collections Framework.

Comment: interesting question. Additional question: wouldn't `setB.stream().anyMatch(setA::contains)` perform better than `setA.stream....` ? It's my understanding that `contains` performs in O(1) on a Set vs O(n) on a list. So better iterate 10 times and check `contains` on 100 elements than iterate 100 times and check `contains` on a list.

Answer (score 3):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<String, String> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        map.put(RandomStringUtils.randomNumeric(5), RandomStringUtils.randomNumeric(5));
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        list.add(RandomStringUtils.randomNumeric(5));
    }

    Set<String> set = new HashSet<>(list);

    List<Runnable> methods = new ArrayList<>();
    methods.add(() -> { Collections.disjoint(map.keySet(), list); });
    methods.add(() -> { Collections.disjoint(list, map.keySet()); });

    methods.add(() -> { map.keySet().stream().anyMatch(list::contains); });
    methods.add(() -> { list.stream().anyMatch(map.keySet()::contains); });

    methods.add(() -> { Sets.intersection(map.keySet(), set).isEmpty(); });
    methods.add(() -> { Sets.intersection(set, map.keySet()).isEmpty(); });

    methods.add(() -> { CollectionUtils.containsAny(map.keySet(), list); });
    methods.add(() -> { CollectionUtils.containsAny(list, map.keySet()); });

    for (Runnable method : methods) {
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
            method.run();
        }
        long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("took " + (end - start));
    }

}
```

And the winner iiis `Collections.disjoint`

```
took 15
took 32
took 484
took 62
took 157
took 47
took 24
took 32
```

Comment: Although I would be cautious to not just take `Collections.disjoint` as the *fastest* solution for every problem - this is a very interesting comparison. I certainly never thought that the simple `stream - contains` could have such different outcomes if you invert the collections. Did you run it for other/larger collections/constellations as well?

Answer (score 1):

`setA.stream().anyMatch(setB::contains)` will be best because all the other options will be non-lazy evaluation and will be performed on all the elements.

For the stream, it will be lazy evaluation and will be returned once any match is found.

Also, from [Documentation of CollectionUtils.containsAny()](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/CollectionUtils.html#containsAny-java.util.Collection-java.util.Collection-)

> In other words, this method returns true iff the intersection(java.lang.Iterable, java.lang.Iterable) of coll1 and coll2 is not empty.

Comment: Pretty sure `CollectionUtils.containsAny()` also returns immediately once a match is found. Documentation specifies semantics, not the way it is implemented.

Comment: @doublep I can’t deny what you are saying

Comment: @RahulKumar I looked at the [implementation](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/src-html/org/apache/commons/collections4/CollectionUtils.html) of the CollectionUtils and basically it loops over the *smaller collection* and checks on every element if it is contained in the *greater collection*. So their doc does not directly relate to the implementation. IMHO this is simply for convenience and should actually have  the same complexity as `setA.stream.anyMatch(setB::contains)`. So I would prefer the stream as well.

Comment: @GameDroids I also checked the same. It is efficient but I would prefer stream because we can use 'parallel stream' to speed up execution further. (disclaimer: not checked myself)